# How to use (sql =any) .Any() of linq to entities lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, lambda

i want something like

```
var o = db.Persons.Where(x=>x.Id in (1, 2));
```

or

```
var o = db.Persons.Where(x=>x.Id =any (1, 2));
```

### to get a list of Persons that the id is in (1, 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var o = db.Persons.Where(x=> new[]{1, 2}.Contains(x.Id));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var keys = new List<int>{1,2,3}; //This contains the collection of your Id
var o = db.Persons.Where(x=>keys.Contains(x.Id));
```